# Power BI Slicer on one table not fitering joined table

Tags: powerbi, slicers

My relationship between two tables looks like this:
[image]

I use a single select slicer that filters the table [ExhibitorClass_Details]. But it is not filtering the joined table [EventMax_Details]:

[image]

Why does my slicer not filter the joined table, what am I missing?

How can I make the slicer filter both tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Solution was to go under `Manage Relationships` and set up the "cross filter direktion":

[image]

Result:
[image]

Comment: Thanks. This helped in a related problem of mine. Searched all through Power BI Community forum with no clue. It is so easy to find an answer on SO.